# Como evitar inyeccion en ventanas modales en asp .net mvc core?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, web, asp.net-core, dom

Cordial saludo:

Estoy usando en mi proyecto Modals de Materializecss, y veo un detalle que me preocupa: Al darle a cualquier navegador "inpeccionar codigo" veo que esta el html del form o de lo que sea que necesito mostrar en la ventana modal sin haber accionado el botón o ancla para que la muestre, ya que ello es una puerta abierta para a inyeccion o ataque al DOM de la pagina.

En el formulario estoy usando una vista parcial pensando en que ello evitaba esa situación

En ese caso: Como evitar la posible inyeccion o ataque al DOM al momento de usar ventanas modales ?

Gracias por su atención.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No me queda claro cuál es el riesgo de que el formulario esté en el DOM desde la carga de la página, si alguien quiere atacar tu sitio, buscará la forma, esperando a que aparezcan elementos nuevos y buscando vulnerabilidades que, generalmente, ocurren por falta de validación del lado del servidor.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer la carga de esa vista parcial solo hasta que el cliente presione un botón, o en cualquier acción que puedas cachar con JavaScript, y ejecutar una llamada Ajax.

Tu div quedaría sin la carga inicial:

```
...
    <div class="ct-chart card z-depth-2 border-radius-6">
        <div class="card-content" id="vista_parcial" />
    </div>
...
```

y una llamada ajax para cargar la vista parcial

```
<script>
function LoadSubrogationRecovery() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'controlador/action_method',
        success: function (viewHTML) {
            $("#vista_parcial").html(viewHTML);
        },
        error: function (errorData) { onError(errorData); }
    });
}
</script>
```